# Override read/write function calls to an SQLite database file

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to override the read/write I/O functions to the SQLite file, so that we can provide custom implementation of such functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into writing your own VFS layer.  See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html) for more details.

Specifically, the section [sqlite3_io_methods](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/io_methods.html).

Comment: Can I use this method to override the functions for SQLite on iPhone?